# Align DIVs with overflow: auto

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items, and at the bottom of the list I have a placeholder-item to add it to list above. In my real-life-example I need to show a "+"-icon at the right side. As the scrollbar appears and disappears depending on how many items are in the list, the right side of the DIVs are sometimes not aligned.

I tried to show that with the red and green color. I know I could just give the green DIV a padding; but if the scrollbar is not showing, then the "+"-icons will not be aligned again.

How can I solve this?

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <div style="height: 100px; overflow: auto; background-color: red;">
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">
    <div>Footer Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try: https://kingsora.github.io/OverlayScrollbars/#!demos/basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by moving the footer `DIV` into the overflow-container and then using `position: sticky`:

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <div style="max-height: 100px; overflow: auto; background-color: red; position: relative;">
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; position: sticky; bottom: 0;">
      <div>Footer Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <div style="max-height: 100px; overflow: auto; background-color: red; position: relative;">
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div>Scrollable Item</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; position: sticky; bottom: 0;">
      <div>Footer Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position: relative` on your items and `position: absolute` on the div containing the `+`. You can then position the `+` in the item using `left` and `top`.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
}

.scrollable {
  height: 100px; 
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
}

.plus {
  left: 170px;
  top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="item">Footer Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
    <div class="item">Scrollable Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="item">Footer Item<div class="plus">+</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It could be a good plan B, what I don't quite like about the solution is that the "+" is indented from the right side even when there is no scrollbar.